# Django NoReverseMatch when i try add href to the navbar

Tags: python, django

Hey i learning django from Youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PX_eVxg5jM
But i have a problem. When I add another link in the navigation in base.html I get this error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post-new' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/new/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'post-new' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/new/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\kacpe\dev\blog\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 673
Python Executable:  C:\Users\kacpe\dev\blog\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\kacpe\\dev\\blog\\blog',
 'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\dev\\blog\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\dev\\blog\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\dev\\blog\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\dev\\blog\\Scripts',
 'c:\\python37\\Lib',
 'c:\\python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\dev\\blog',
 'C:\\Users\\kacpe\\dev\\blog\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Pon, 18 Lis 2019 00:37:52 +0100
```

This is what the rest of my files look like.

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myblog/main.css' %}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Django Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'myblog-home' %}">Django Blog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'myblog-home' %}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'myblog-about' %}">About</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-new' %}">New Post</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                    {{ message }}
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='myblog-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='myblog-about'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/<int:pk>/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView,
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from .models import Post


# def home_page(request):
#     context = {
#         'posts': Post.objects.all()
#     }
#     return render(request, 'myblog/home_page.html', context)

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'myblog/home_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'myblog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

When I try `{% url 'post-new' 1 %}` no error occurs, but when i try `{% url 'post-new' posts.id %}` It appears:

```
NoReverseMatch at /post/new/1/
Reverse for 'post-new' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/new/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

In the video above, everything works properly, but I have this problem. I was looking for solutions but nothing helped. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Create view doesn't need a pk or id, so correct your url as below:

```
path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-new')
```